# Hibernate Envers based on Field level value change

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

**Problem Summary:** Need to take snapshot of a database row only when a particular field changes using Hibernate Envers.

**Technologies Used:** `Spring Boot`, `Spring Data JPA`, `Hibernate Envers 5.2.10`

**Current Behavior:** Currently i have Hibernate Envers running and it audits the table changes that are made to each object.

**Step 1: User Table:** When new user registered, initially the account_status will be EMAIL_VERIFICATION_PENDING

```
id  user_name  email_id         phone_number   account_status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234   EMAIL_VERIFICATION_PENDING
```

**User Audit Table**

```
id  REV REVTYPE user_name  email_id        phone_number  account_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1   0       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 EMAIL_VERIFICATION_PENDING
```

**Step 2: User Table** When Email verification completed, then the account_status changed to PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING

```
id  user_name  email_id         phone_number   account_status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234   PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
```

**User Audit Table looks like**

```
id  REV REVTYPE user_name  email_id        phone_number  account_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1   0       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 EMAIL_VERIFICATION_PENDING
2   2   1       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
```

**Step 3: User Table:** User changed their phone number

```
id  user_name  email_id         phone_number   account_status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 test_user  test@sample.com  111-222-3333   PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
```

**Now User Audit Table looks like**

```
id  REV REVTYPE user_name  email_id        phone_number  account_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1   0       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 EMAIL_VERIFICATION_PENDING
2   2   1       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
3   3   1       test_user  test@sample.com  111-222-3333 PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
```

**Step 4: User Table:** When Phone verification completed, then the account_status changed to ACTIVE

```
id  user_name  email_id         phone_number   account_status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
101 test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234   ACTIVE
```

**And User Audit Table looks like**

```
id  REV REVTYPE user_name  email_id        phone_number  account_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1   0       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 EMAIL_VERIFICATION_PENDING
2   2   1       test_user  test@sample.com  123-123-1234 PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
3   3   1       test_user  test@sample.com  111-222-3333 PHONE_VERIFICATION_PENDING
4   4   1       test_user  test@sample.com  111-222-3333 ACTIVE
```

*Notice: whenever any changes in user table, Hibernate Envers create new revision and adds entry in the audit table*

**Trying to achieve:** When any changes in account_status, Hiberate Envers create new revision. **Basically, i want to avoid revision number 3 from audit table. Which means i dont want to audit for the phone number change**

Is there any way i can control Hibernate Envers to audit only on specific field level changes (like account_status) ?

Can anyone help me the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could accomplish that.

As you know Envers ships with two annotations, `@Audited` and `@NotAudited`.

The typical norm use case is that users place the `@Audited` annotation at the class level to indicate that Envers should track all field changes and it does precisely that.

If there is a field in this use case you wish not to track, you simply annotate that field with the other annotation, `@NotAudited`, as shown here:

```
@Audited
@Entity
class User {
  ...
  @NotAudited
  private String phoneNumber;
}
```

This is a super easy way to eliminate a small number of fields from the audit table when you're more interested in a majority of fields to be tracked.  But sometimes users are interested in the inverse approach, track only a subset of fields where a majority are not of interest.

In this case, its useful not to annotate the class itself but instead annotate the specific fields that must be audited / tracked, as shown here:

```
@Entity
class User {
  private String phoneNumber;
  @Audited
  private UserStatus status;
}
```

In this case, the `phoneNumber` is not audited while the `status` property will be.

While you can place the `@Audited` annotation on the primary key field(s) of your entity, it isn't required.  Envers automatically picks up and applies the primary key values anyway, so that helps avoid too much verbosity here too.

Comment: Placing specific annotation on fields does audit just those fields but it still adds a new entry (a duplicate) if say phoneNumber changes. Do we need to put '@NotAudited' on phoneNumber?